# Django: Form is not saving to database

Tags: python, django, forms, save

I've seen similar types of problems on here but I still haven't been able to work out my problem. When I save **PhotographerProfileForm** in my view, the form is rendered correctly but after clicking update/submit nothing is actually saved.

No errors are shown either.

What I have now are the fields are prepopulated and I would like the ability to save over these in the database, but nothing happens and at the moment you can only update it from the admin panel.

---

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class PhotographerProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

User.profile = property(lambda u: PhotographerProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])


from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
    if created:
        profile, new = PhotographerProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
```

---

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^profile/$', 'photoprofile.views.photographer_profile', name = 'photographer_profile'),
url(r'^profile/portfolio/$', 'photoprofile.views.photographer_portfolio', name='photographer_portfolio'),
```

]

---

views.py

```
@login_required


def photographer_profile(request):
    photographerProfile = PhotographerProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    form = PhotographerProfileForm(initial={'bio':photographerProfile.bio,     'location':photographerProfile.location})#This means you can prepoulate it
    return render_to_response('photographerprofile.html',{'form':form},  RequestContext(request))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PhotographerProfileForm(request.POST, instance = request.user.profile,)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/profile')

    else:
        user = request.user
        profile = user.profile
        form = PhotographerProfileForm()

    return render(request, 'photographerprofile.html', {'form':form})

def photographer_portfolio(request):
    photographerProfile = PhotographerProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    return render_to_response('photographerportfolio.html', {'photographerProfile':photographerProfile}, RequestContext(request))
```

---

forms.py

```
class PhotographerProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = PhotographerProfile
    exclude = ('user',)
```

---

photographerprofile.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}

<h2> Profile</h2>

{% for field in form %}
{{ field.error}}

{% endfor %}

<form action='/accounts/profile/' method='post'>
{% csrf_token %}
{{form|crispy}}

    <input type='submit' value='Update'/>

    <p>Click <a href='/accounts/profile/portfolio/'>here</a> to view portfolio.    </p>

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You return in the third line of your view, before the form has been processed. Remove that line.

Comment: return render_to_response('photographerprofile.html',{'form':form},  RequestContext(request))  . this line?  Nothing happens

Comment: Yes, remove that line completely.

Comment: Yup, I've removed it. It doesn't seem to do anything  and it also removes the pre populated data.

Comment: Try moving the line to replace the final render. Move first render_to_response `return render_to_response('photographerprofile.html',{'form':form},  RequestContext(request))` after `return render_to_response('photographerprofile.html',{'form':form},  RequestContext(request))`. Then completely remove `return render_to_response('photographerprofile.html',{'form':form},  RequestContext(request))`

You're not providing the RequestContext by completely removing it. Give me a minute as well, and I'll review the rest of the code.

Comment: @AaronLayfield Sorry, just wondering if you had had a chance to look at it. Spent the whole day restarting and the same problem occurs. I can't save over the data from the form

Comment: Sorry been busy working on a personal project. Whats the outcome when you remove that 3rd line in the view? Does anything change? Can you show me the form results post rendering